# How do I add a rectangle to a panel?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing

This is the code I use to create the panel and the rectangle, but it is not working:

```
Public ribbon_holder As New Panel
Public BluePen As New Pen(Main.mi_blue, 5)

With ribbon_holder
  .Parent = Main
  .Width = Main.Width
  .Height = 75
  .BackColor = Color.White
  .BringToFront()
End With

Dim myGraphics As Graphics = ribbon_holder.CreateGraphics
myGraphics.DrawRectangle(BluePen, 0, 0, 100, 50)
```

I'm simply trying to create an empty rectangle inside my panel.
Thanks.

Comment: This drawing is likely being overwritten by the default Form.Paint method, consider adding a paint event and paint it there using the PaintEventArgs Graphics object provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that variable with the `WithEvents` modifier so you can attach the paint event like below:

```
Friend WithEvents ribbon_holder As New Panel

Private Sub rh_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles ribbon_holder.Paint
 'GDI drawing in here persist
 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(BluePen, 0, 0, 100, 50)
End Sub
```